# Recursively get ids of tree

Tags: t-sql, cte, recursive

I have a table foo.

[image]

So we have a hiearchical object structure where on foo has one parent (or none) and a list of children.

What I want is a sql statement that lists all id:s that can be found either traversing upwards and downwards in that hierarchy.

How?

My current attempt is

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetChain]
    @starting_id int
AS
BEGIN
    WITH chainIDsUpwards AS
    (
        SELECT id, parent_id FROM foo
        WHERE parent_id IS NULL

        UNION ALL

        SELECT foo.id, foo.parent_id FROM foo
        JOIN chainIDsUpwards p ON foo.parent_id = p.id
    ),
    chainIDsDownwards AS
    (
        SELECT id, parent_id FROM foo

        UNION ALL

        SELECT foo.id, foo.parent_id FROM foo
        JOIN chainIDsDownwards c ON foo.id = c.parent_id
    )

    SELECT * FROM chainIDsUpwards WHERE id = @starting_id
    UNION
    SELECT * FROM chainIDsDownwards WHERE id = @starting_id
END
```

but it does only give me a single row.

## edit

Sample data:

[image: sample data]

EXEC [GetChain] @starting_id = 5

returns

[image: only one row as result]

but I expect:

- 5, 2
- 2, 1
- 1, null
- 11, 5

Fiddle at https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=aeaf40c57b3940ce725dccf553a8d9e2

## edit 2

I thought I had found the correct sql being

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetChain]
    @starting_id int
AS
BEGIN
    WITH chainIDsUpwards AS
    (
        SELECT id, parent_id FROM foo WHERE id = @starting_id

        UNION ALL

        SELECT foo.id, foo.parent_id FROM foo
        JOIN chainIDsUpwards p ON p.id = foo.parent_id
    ),
    chainIDsDownwards AS
    (
        SELECT id, parent_id FROM foo WHERE parent_id = @starting_id

        UNION ALL

        SELECT foo.id, foo.parent_id FROM foo
        JOIN chainIDsDownwards c ON foo.id = c.parent_id
    ),
    chainIDs AS
    (
        SELECT id FROM chainIDsUpwards
        UNION
        SELECT id FROM chainIDsDownwards
    )

    SELECT id FROM chainIDs
END
```

but that will not find any parents for 9. It only finds 9 itself, but not 3 or 1.

Fiddle at https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=10041653e78b52bc8ec0e3c40cfff7a0

Comment: Can you add some sample data (as insert statements) that illustrates the problem?

Comment: I added sample data @Lennart

Comment: Images of data are not that useful. I suggest you use a service like https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019 and post back the url

Comment: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=aeaf40c57b3940ce725dccf553a8d9e2

Answer (score 2):

Basically, you need to move your @starting_id predicate to the base case of the recursive part:

```
WITH chainIDsUpwards AS
(
    SELECT id, parent_id FROM foo
    WHERE id = @starting_id

    UNION ALL

    SELECT foo.id, foo.parent_id FROM foo
    JOIN chainIDsUpwards p ON foo.id = p.parent_id
)
SELECT * FROM chainIDsUpwards;
```

If you put the predicate as:

```
SELECT * FROM chainIDsUpwards WHERE ...;
```

it will filter all rows that do not satisfy the predicate.

I also believe that you need to change the join clause in both cte:s if you want the behavior to correspond with the name. I find it easier mentally to start with the cte in the join like:

```
SELECT foo.id, foo.parent_id 
FROM chainIDsUpwards p
JOIN foo 
    ON p.parent_id = foo.id
```

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&sample=adventureworks&fiddle=d03658db07a88cf2bde5371d58c13ede)

Answer (score 1):

Just for funsies.

Rather than having two subqueries (one for ancestors and one for descendants), my preference is to map the entire hierarchy in a single statement and search above and below in the node in question based on that.

Given an additional computed column marking parentless (or self-parent) entities as "`is_root` = 1", for a hierarchy of the form...

```
 1
 |\
 2 3
  / \
 7   4

 5
  \
   6
```

...my example code would be...

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetChain]
    @starting_id int
AS
BEGIN
-- https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/273695/68127
    WITH cte AS (
        SELECT 
            id, 
            parent_id,
            depth = 0,
            '/'+convert(varchar(max),id) as _path
        FROM foo
        WHERE is_root = 1
        UNION ALL
        SELECT 
            foo.id, 
            foo.parent_id,
            depth + 1,
            _path + '/'+convert(varchar(max),foo.id)
        FROM cte
        JOIN foo ON foo.parent_id = cte.id
        where cte.depth < 100 -- i can never remember the maxrecursion hint syntax
            and foo.is_root = 0
    )
    SELECT * 
    FROM cte 
    where exists ( -- children (and self)
        select 1
        from string_split(_path,'/') ss
        where ss.value = @starting_id
    ) or cte.id in ( -- parents (and self)
        select ss.[value]
        from cte b
        cross apply string_split(b._path,'/') ss
        where b.id = @starting_id
    )
    order by _path
END
```

... which gives us...

```sql
exec getChain 3;
/*
we expect the following nodes

 1
  \
   3
  / \
 7   4
 
2 is excluded because it is a sibling of 3, 
but not an ancestor or descendant
*/
```

[Full db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=efc4efda19edfd92695e5fc4337c5648)

Comment: Too bad I cannot freely add the column is_root!

Comment: That is a bummer; but you can drop-in replace it with the expression given in the computed column in the fiddle `iif(id=parent_id,1,0))`, although you may need to be sensible about scoping issues. Probably makes more sense (and is definitely more human readable) to just use the original expression `id=parent_id`, really

Comment: What's the difference between is_root = 1 and parent_id is null?

Comment: @Lennart none really. i just prefer marking root entities as own-parent rather than null-parent in these scenarios. It allows for the parent_id column to be set `not null` as well.

Comment: You dont need an extra attribute in that case either, id = parent_id is sufficient.